# How to open url's in ListView with OnItemTapped - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a ListView with `Title` and `Url`.

I want when users click on the url to open the current url with browser.

My ListView:

```
  <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="lstNews" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTapped="LoadNews">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid BackgroundColor="#454545">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="2"></RowDefinition>

                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TitleNews}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="#2bff00" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding UrlNews}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <BoxView Color="#2bff00" HeightRequest="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SmartCryptoWorld.Models;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SmartCryptoWorld
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public List<NewsBody> NewsList = new List<NewsBody>()
        {

        };

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async Task GetAPI()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://crypto-news-live.p.rapidapi.com/news/coindesk"),
                Headers =
            {
                { "x-rapidapi-host", "crypto-news-live.p.rapidapi.com" },
                { "x-rapidapi-key", "51569aba99mshf9e839fcfce791bp16c0dbjsn9ced6dba7472" },
            },
            };
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                var news = new News();
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var newsBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NewsBody>>(body);
                news.CryptoNews = newsBody;
                lstNews.ItemsSource = newsBody;
                newsBody = NewsList;
            }
        }

        void ButtonInfo(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _ = GetAPI();
        }

        void LoadNews(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (var item in NewsList)
            {
                Launcher.OpenAsync(item.UrlNews);
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

I want to tap on the Label on grid.row 1 "UrlNews" to be tapped and open the current url.

[image: How to open the urls ?]

Comment: Lookup the doco on HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options#expansion

Comment: One stackoverflow post = 1 question. Please split up your post in two.

Comment: Can you check I did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ItemTapped`

```
<ListView ItemTapped="LoadNews" ... />
```

in your code behind

```
protected void LoadNews(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs args)
{
  var item = (MyItemClass)args.Item;
  Launcher.OpenAsync(item.UrlNews);
}
```

Comment: Can you check my code behind ListView because my code doesn't work ?

Comment: why are you opening EVERY item in your list when they tap one item?

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: Why would you want to?  I don't think the device really supports a method to open multiple web pages at once

Comment: I want to open only the link that is clicked on each line when clicking on the link Grid.Row=1

Comment: that is the code I put in my answer.  The code you put in your edit question does not match my code at all

Comment: what should I put in place MyItemClass  ?

Comment: whatever class you are using for the ItemsSource.  Probably `NewsBody`?

Comment: When I use  var item = (NewsBody)args.Item; I receive error: The name 'args' does not exist in the current context

Comment: `args` is the 2nd parameter to the event handler.  Did you name it something different?

Comment: yes, the name is "e" my fall, now works fine ! Thank you..